# Vaadin starter app's tabs do not behave like standard "tabs" in an app

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In using Vaadin's starter package to create my app, I noticed that when a user clicks from one tab to another and then back to the original tab, the *original* screen/view from the original tab is gone (i.e., it's reset). I think this is because the vaadin starter package is not treating the different menu options like "tabs in an app", but more like "popup dialog boxes" that reset to the default each time the user clicks on it. (I think this is because, behinds the scenes, each 'menu item' reopens up a new url). Is it possible to have the 'tabs' behave more like tabs in a fat-app application, so that a user's settings are not lost? If so, what's the easiest way to do so when using vaadin's starter code?

[image: screenshot of standard vaadin start screen]

Vaadin Details -->

```
Flow: 24.3.7
Vaadin: 24.3.7
Java: Eclipse Adoptium 21.0.1
OS: amd64 Linux 5.15.0-1053-gcp
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Live reload: Java active
          (Spring Boot Devtools): Front end active
```

Comment: have you tried https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/advanced/preserving-state-on-refresh

Comment: @cfrick just tried; didn't work